# Is using the user's default PDF viewer better than using the internal Google PDF viewer

Tags: google

I'm figuring out some Google Policy Settings, which should be deployed via GPO and I was wondering if [`AlwaysOpenPdfExternally`](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::AlwaysOpenPdfExternally&Language=en-gb), which disables the Google PDF viewer and opens the device's default PDF viewer, has any security advantage or other advantage over using the internal Google PDF viewer.

Comment: It depends on which option has more security vulnerabilities? One is unknown (whatever the device uses) and the one is known. Which situation are you more comfortable with from a risk perspective?